# If a short circuit occured across the mosfet would anything happen in this scenario?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, short-circuit

I am just confused about understanding a simple concept.

For the following circuit:

[image]

Say the blue line acts as a short for whatever reason. If the LED has a forward voltage drop of 23 V and forward current of 30mA (LED contains everything it needs for this example (as in resistor is inside just for this example))

If we don't have a resistor and just a wire connecting the MCU to the mosfet, when the short occurs will the current still remain at 30 mA? As in the current would not become infinite/very large? Essentially nothing will change except the current will be continuously entering the MCU pin and could potentially blow teh MCU if the 30mA exceeded its rating?

**In short:
Essentially I just want to know that if a short occurred over the mosfet and say the MCU pin was low for that state, will the current remain the same at 30mA due to the limiting resistor of the LED. As in that's all that would happen (and obviously that the MCU will always have current going into it)**

Comment: Sorry the LED contains the resistor inside (but yeah I understand it needs the Resistor)

Comment: The LED has a forward voltage of 24V? You'll need more than 24V supply then. It is only 30mA of current if the current limiting resistor for it is selected to give 30mA. You need to add a resistor to it otherwise the LED will likely be ruined. What is the voltage from the MCU? Once you have these factors, redraw the circuit without the MOSFET and with a voltage source instead of the MCU. You should be able to solve it from there.

Comment: Not drawing the resistor is confusing! Just include it in the schematic please.

Comment: @Student if the resistor is internal, draw it as an external resistor in your schematic

Comment: @MCG Essentially i just want to know that if a short occurred over the mosfet and say the MCU pin was low for that state, will the current remain the same at 30mA due to the limiting resistor of the LED. As in thats all that would happen (and obviously that the MCU will always have current going into it)

Comment: Again, it is much easier to add the resistor in the schematic. This makes it readable by everybody.

Comment: It's actually straightforward. Current will flow from highest potential to lower potential. If the internal ESD diode cannot handle it, your pin will blow up, or even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the shorts in place this is likely to happen:

I'm assuming that the MCU does not run on 24 V but on a different supply of 5 V.

I'm also assuming that the MOSFET is **broken** and that it behaves as an "open" on all pins.

Then the output of the MCU will be "pulled up" by the LED + resistor + shorts.

That will **forward bias** one of the ESD diodes inside the MCU.

These ESD diodes are present in practically any IC.

This is then the situation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8lLpr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This assumes that the 5 V supply is such that it stays at 5 V.

It is possible that the 5 V supply cannot "absorb" the extra 24 mA and will increase in value. For example to 10 V. That could potentionally damage your MCU!

If the MOSFET is not broken then it will act as a "MOSFET diode" and limit the voltage at the drain to a few volts (slightly more than the Vt of the MOSFET).

Comment: Ok thanks, just a quick question why is it 24 mA? But thanks for the explanation, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Also if like you said the other pins on the mosfet were not open would nothing happen in that scenario then and current would just go straight to ground?

Comment: *why ~24 mA?* Voltage across R1: 24 V - 3 V (D1) - 0.6 V - 5 V = 15.4 V / 680 ohm = 23 mA. In my 24 mA calculation I forgot about D2.

Comment: Yes if the MOSFET is still working then it will act like a diode but dropping Vt (couple of volts). So not "straight to  ground" but with some voltage across it.

Comment: Sorry @Bimpelrekkie, but for "Then the output of the MCU will be "pulled up" by the LED + resistor + shorts" what did you mean by this. As in what causes the output of the MCU to be pulled up? Or are you just saying when the MCU outputs 5V? compared to when its logic low?

Comment: I just look at the circuit, analyze it and predict what happens. If you can't follow that then maybe you need more circuit analysis experience. That requires practice and more practice. I've been doing that (analyzing how circuits work) for more than 30 years so no worries if you don't "see" the solution so quickly.

Comment: Can I just ask quickly say if my MCU can output a maximum current of 20 mA, can anything less than that go back into it in rough terms? I am using a PSOC 5 as my microcontroller and am using strong drive. I was essentially told if the current entering pin than what was teh max current it could output it would be ok for that short duration?

Comment: @Student I'll try to predict what Bimpelrekkie actually meant. D2 will be forward biased and D3 will be reverse biased. Considering that BUF1 and the rest impedances are much higher than D2. Thus, 99% of the current will flow towards D2.

Comment: @Unknown123 That's correct, an output buffer of an MCU generally isn't strong enough to do much in this situation. If it was strong enough it could pull the output low, then the LED would still light up. If the output of the MCU is high (5V) also not much changes, the LED will still run at ~23 mA.

Comment: @Student If you're really worried about the MOSFET breaking then damaging the MCU then the best you can do is make sure R2 is present and make it 1 kohm as that will limit the current and prevent damage. If you're still worried R2 will be shorted, place a few in series. But generally, this doesn't happen unless you do strange things to components like use them outside their rated voltages for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is your initial scenario with 30mA LED current. V1 is the MCU output:

[image]

And this is if you short those nodes:

[image]

So LED current decreases and the MCU out might burn or gets damaged because it gets shorted to ground. But that current passes through MOSFET drain and source also will damage the MOSFET. So eventually the LED will also be off.

Comment: 2287A? I don't think your simulation is providing useful results.

Comment: Yes I didn't add 50 ohm output impedance for MCU just to show the effect.

Comment: I am a little confused on why the current goes to ~2.28kA?

Comment: @Student Because the simulation is not realistic. Ignore those results.

Comment: You can add 50 Ohm output resistance in series with V1.

Comment: You're seeing such huge currents because current is going from the MCU output through the FET to ground; the FET is held on by the 5V source connected to its gate and source, and yet due to the positions of the sources it also has 5V between drain and source, and the model breaks down under those conditions because that's not how you use most types of FET.

Comment: @user16307 Where are you getting 50Ω from?

Comment: @Hearth  Estimate for an equivalent thevenin resistance of a digital output port

Comment: @user16307 On what MCU? Output resistance isn't usually rated but it varies a _lot_.

Comment: @Hearth How much it can vary? MOSFET characteristics can vary as well. The question doesnt provide that how can I know- Based on assumptions.

Comment: @user16307 From ohms to tens of kilohms. The FET characteristics are of less importance to the simulation here anyway.

Comment: @Hearth My point is thats why I didnt add series output impedance. He should add it himself depending on his own MCU.